# How do I wrap an intrinsic component, keeping most of the Props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to wrap a standard button with my own React functional component, 
but I want the user of the new component to be able to set 
almost all of the underlying button's props. Of course, I want to maintain the proper typing, so if WrappedButton encloses a `button`, then

```js
<WrappedButton formNoValidate={true} onClick={handleClick} />
```

will compile correctly but

```js
<WrappedButton formNoValidate={5} onKrapnik={handleClick} />
```

will not, both because `formNoValidate` is typed as a boolean and `onKrapnik` does not exist.

Obviously, I don't want to make an exhaustive (and fragile) list of the underlying component's legal props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original component has some number of props.  For each prop, 
you might want to

- pass it through untouched
- modify in in some fashion
- omit it
- change its type

You also might want to add some new props of your own. Let's take a simple case, you just want to add some new props. I'm making a new kind of button called `MultiClick`, which adds
an optional prop:

```js
type MultiClickProps = {
  clickCount?: number;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"];

const MultiClick: React.FC<MultiClickProps> = ({
  clickCount = 2,
  ...buttonProps
}) => {
// do some stuff
  return (
    <button {...buttonProps} />
  );
};
```

Of course, that's not very useful: how would the "some stuff" do anything meaningful if the end result is to return a button with all the props passed through unmodified?

So you might want to intercept and modify some props:

```js
const MultiClick: React.FC<MultiClickProps> = ({
  clickCount = 2,
  onClick,
  ...buttonProps
}) => {
  const handleClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
  ) => {
    // do some stuff
    onClick(event);
  };

  return (
    <button {...buttonProps} onClick={handleClick}/>
  );
};
```

This way, there is an opportunity to actually interact with the actions of the wrapped component.

Now let's say you don't like the "event" argument to the onClick
and want to substitute something else, a number.  To change a type, 
you actually have to omit the old prop and re-write it, like so:

```js
type MultiClickProps = {
  clickCount?: number;
  onClick: (n: number) => void;
} & Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"], 'onClick'>;
```

You can see the finished code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9qjuqu).

Incidentally, all this depends on the existence of JSX.IntrinsicElements, which the React people were kind enough to provide.  Suppose you are trying to wrap a functional component from some library that did *not* export a neat props type?

Fortunately, you can generate your own props type for any functional component written in Typescript, with this:

```js
type PropsOf<T> =
    T extends React.FunctionComponent<infer U> ? U : never;
```

which if applied to the function above, like so:

```js
type MultiClickProps = PropsOf<typeof MultiClick>;
```

would evaluate to something like

```js
type MultiClickProps = {
    clickCount?: number;
} & React.ClassAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
```

Comment: Wait, but... why? You don't have to use typings for HTML elements since the types are built-in by default. You have overcomplicated it by using spread syntax when passing props to `<button>`. Why not simply pass all the props that are accepted by button separately? There are not so many of them after all... (at least not so many of these props that are used on a daily basis)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly (and I'm not sure I do), I want to use the interface defined for the built-in types to help define the type for my function.  Suppose someone passes in some obscure prop, like `formNoValidate`, to my MultiClick prop.  I would want the compiler to allow that, and insist it be passed a boolean, because that's the required type, while forbidding nonsense properties.

Comment: Then the only thing you have to do is omit that single prop. If you really want to insist with spread syntax, just use `const { formNoValidate, ...rest } = props` and simply `<button {...rest} />`. TypeScript will understand it.

Comment: @kinduser — one of us is missing the point.  It might be you: the problem is how to properly type the wrapping function, not how to invoke the wrapping function.

Comment: @kinduser — I edited the question to (I hope) make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks, but still imo it's a little bit overcomplicated. If you want to accept every native button prop, just add the type (`& IntrinsicButtonProps` or whatever its called) and thats all. What's more - `onClick: (n: number) => void;` won't happen ever, since native onlick always return an event as the first arg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212495/discussion-between-malvolio-and-kind-user).