# React, styled-components and TypeScript: How to wrap a styled component in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to create a wrapper for my styled component but I'm having trouble getting the types right.

Let's say I have a styled component like this:

```js
const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;
```

Now I want to create a wrapper component that contains this styled button, eg. like this:

```js
const WrappedButton: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <div>
    <Button {...rest}>{children}</Button>
  </div>
);
```

Now this all works fine, but what I actually want is the `WrappedButton` component **to accept all props that the `Button` component would accept and pass them along to the wrapped `Button` component**.

So for example I want this to compile, as type is a valid prop of a HTML button element (and therefore also a valid prop of the Button component, but not when the Button component is wrapped):

```js
// TypeScript will throw an error because "type" is not a valid prop of WrappedButton. 
const MyComponent = () => <WrappedButton type="submit">Test</WrappedButton>
```

I know I can make "type" a prop of the WrappedComponent, but that's not the point, I want the WrappedComponent **to accept all props that a normal HTML button would accept**.

EDIT: Also I need all styled-component specific props on the wrapped component, such as the `as` prop of styled-components. Here's an updated version of the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-styled-components-forked-3o20j?file=/src/index.tsx

I have tried so many things but TypeScript is always complaining. I have also searched the docs and the internet but have not found anything.

Answer (score 2):

I believe You are asking about `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`.

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;


type ButtonProps = {
} & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;


const WrappedButton: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
    <div>
        <Button {...rest}>{children}</Button>
    </div>
);
```

If you want to use raw html `<button>`, you mignt be interested in: `JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"];`

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429497/how-do-i-wrap-an-intrinsic-component-keeping-most-of-the-props)

**UPDATE**
The quick and dirty solution would be :

```js
type ButtonProps = {
} & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & { as?: string | React.ComponentType<any> };
```

But it is not generic.

There is `StyledComponentPropsWithAs` type in SC typings, but it is not exported (

Comment: This *almost* works, the only problem with this solution is that like this I don't have the props of the styled-component on the wrapped component. For example if I add the `as` prop to the `WrappedButton` TypeScript will not compile. See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-styled-components-forked-3o20j?file=/src/index.tsx

Sorry I did not mention that this is a requirement in my question, I will update the question accordingly

Comment: AFAIK, `as` does not exist on raw html button

Comment: Exactly, but it exists on a styled-component created with styled.button... I also want the wrapper component to accept all of the props of the wrapped styled-component (such as `as`)

Comment: Sorry, I can't find in docs information about `as` attribute. Is this your custom property?

Comment: No, this is a prop of styled-components: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to suppress native attributes you could do something like this:

```
interface Props {
  type?: 'error' | 'success'
}

type OmitNativeAttrs = Omit<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, keyof Props>
export type ButtonProps = Props & OmitNativeAttrs
```