# Spread element props in a styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to create a component in React that wraps a paragraph element, and at the same time extends its props from the HTML props so I can still use the props of the

element itself. Its styled by using styled components. But I'm not able to pass the rest of the props to it

I tried two approaches.

In the first one this is the component I created:

```
import React from "react";
import "./text.css";
import { styled } from "styled-components";

interface props extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLParagraphElement> {
  textSize?: number;
}

const Paragraph = styled.p<{ $textSize: number }>`
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size: ${(props) => props.$textSize};
`;

export default function Text({ textSize = 14, children, ...props }: props) {
  return (
    <Paragraph {...props} $textSize={textSize}>
      {children}
    </Paragraph>
  );
}
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```
<Text textSize={20}>Hello World</Text>
```

I tried declaring the props type by extending it from the HTMLProps, and I added a textSize to it.
I declared the paragraph by using the styled.p function and declared the textSize prop
So, when I use that styled Paragraph component, I'm sending the textSize which works good because it's declared in the styled.p but when attempting to spread the rest of the props I receive the following typescript error

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLParagraphElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 264 more ...; $textSize: number; } & Partial<...> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: ReactNode; $textSize: number; accept?: string | undefined; acceptCharset?: string | undefined; action?: string | undefined; allowFullScreen?: boolean | undefined; ... 363 more ...; key?: Key | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ slot?: string | undefined; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; title?: string | undefined; ref?: ((instance: HTMLParagraphElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined; ... 264 more ...; $textSize: number; }'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'LegacyRef<HTMLParagraphElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLParagraphElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement> | null | undefined'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLParagraphElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement> | null | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"web", string, { $textSize: number; }, never, string>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"web", string, { $textSize: number; }, never, string>, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: ReactNode; $textSize: number; accept?: string | undefined; acceptCharset?: string | undefined; action?: string | undefined; allowFullScreen?: boolean | undefined; ... 363 more ...; key?: Key | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { $textSize: number; } & Partial<{}> & { theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; } & { as?: string | undefined; forwardedAs?: string | undefined; }'.
      Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { $textSize: number; } & Partial<{}> & { theme?: DefaultTheme | undefined; } & { as?: string | undefined; forwardedAs?: string | undefined; }'.
    14 | export default function Text({ textSize = 14, children, ...props }: props) {
    15 |   return (
  > 16 |     <Paragraph {...props} $textSize={textSize}>
       |      ^^^^^^^^^
    17 |       {children}
    18 |     </Paragraph>
    19 |   );
```

I also tried doing it like this trying to mimic the instructions in this question [React, styled-components and TypeScript: How to wrap a styled component in a functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625179/react-styled-components-and-typescript-how-to-wrap-a-styled-component-in-a-fun):

```
import React from "react";
import "./text.css";
import { styled } from "styled-components";

interface props extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLParagraphElement> {
  $textSize?: number;
}

const Paragraph = styled.p<props>`
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size: ${(props) => props.$textSize};
  color: white;
`;

export default function Text({ $textSize = 14, children, ...props }: props) {
  return (
    <Paragraph $textSize {...props}>
      {children}
    </Paragraph>
  );
}
```

But didn't work either. This is the error for this approach:

```
ERROR in src/globalComponents/Text/index.tsx:17:16
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { $textSize?: number | undefined; cite?: string | undefined; data?: string | undefined; form?: string | undefined; label?: string | undefined; slot?: string | undefined; span?: number | undefined; ... 362 more ...; wrap?: string | undefined; } & Partial<...> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"web", string, props, never, string>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"web", string, props, never, string>, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    15 | export default function Text({ $textSize = 14, children, ...props }: props) {
    16 |   return (
  > 17 |     <Paragraph $textSize {...props}>
       |                ^^^^^^^^^
    18 |       {children}
    19 |     </Paragraph>
    20 |   );
```

I'm kinda confused, to be honest. Hope you can be patient with me if I'm being stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out my second approach was kind of in the right way. I managed to solve it by doing it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./text.css";
import { colors } from "@/globalVars/theme";
import { styled } from "styled-components";

interface props extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLParagraphElement> {
  $textSize?: number;
}

const Paragraph = styled.p<props>`
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size: ${(props) => props.$textSize}px;
  color: ${colors.textBlack};
`;

export default function Text({ $textSize = 16, children, ...rest }: props) {
  return (
    <Paragraph $textSize={$textSize} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Paragraph>
  );
}
```

The problem I had is I was just sending the props to Paragraph like this:

```
<Paragraph $textSize {...props}>
```

Which, was taken as a boolean instead of the value for some reason. Now, when I explicitly tell it what value I want it works:

```
<Paragraph $textSize={$textSize} {...rest}>
```